# How to give a context-sensitive grammar for a^nba^nba^nb?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, context-sensitive

I am struggling on this problem since days: $L = \{a^nba^nba^nb \mid n \in \Bbb N\}$. I have to give for this language a context-sensitive grammar.

Comment: What kind of grammar are you looking for?

Comment: Typ1 grammar context-sensitive

Comment: Try adapting a grammar for $\{ a^n b^n c^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar#Examples) gives such a grammar.

Comment: i did. but find nothing...

Comment: Perhaps you should try harder.

Comment: since 5 or 6 days im trying this...

Answer (score 4):

One possible grammar is:

\begin{align}
S&\rightarrow Tb &(1)\\
T&\rightarrow AXY &(2)\\
T&\rightarrow ATXY &(3)\\
YX&\rightarrow YZ &(4)\\
YZ&\rightarrow WZ &(5)\\
WZ&\rightarrow WY &(6)\\
WY &\rightarrow XY &(7)\\
AX &\rightarrow AbA_X &(8)\\
A_XX&\rightarrow A_XA_X &(9)\\
A_XY&\rightarrow A_XbA_Y &(10)\\
A_YY&\rightarrow A_YA_Y &(11)\\
A&\rightarrow a &(12)\\
A_X&\rightarrow a &(13)\\
A_Y&\rightarrow a &(14)
\end{align}

We can generate $A^n(XY)^n$ using Rule (1) to (3). Rule (4) to (7) are used to change $YX$ to $XY$, thus we can generate $A^nX^nY^n$. At last, using Rule (8) to (14) we can generate $a^nba^nba^nb$.

Note we needn't worry that in a pattern $YX$, $Y$ yields to $A_Y$ (or $bA_Y$) before we exchange $X$ and $Y$, because otherwise there is no rule to eliminate $X$ in this pattern.

Answer (score 3):

**Lemma 1**: The non-contracting rule $XY\rightarrow YX$ can be rewritten as context-sensitive rules.
**Proof**: We can replace $XY\rightarrow YX$ with the following four context-sensitive rules,
$\quad XY\rightarrow UY$,
$\quad UY\rightarrow UV$,
$\quad UV\rightarrow UX$,
$\quad UX\rightarrow YX$,
where $U, V$ are new non-terminals.

**Lemma 2**: The non-contracting rule $XY\rightarrow aX$ can be rewritten as context-sensitive rules.
**Proof**: Similarly to lemma 1, we can replace $XY\rightarrow aX$ with the following four rules,
$\quad XY\rightarrow UY$,
$\quad UY\rightarrow UV$,
$\quad UV\rightarrow aV$,
$\quad aV\rightarrow aX$,
where $U, V$ are new non-terminals.

Because of the lemmas, we will include rules like $XY\rightarrow YX$ or $XY\rightarrow aX$ in our context-sensitive grammar with the understanding that each of them represents four context-sensitive rules.

---

The outline of the idea to build the grammar is to let non-terminal $T_1$
"travel" from the left-hand side of ${A_1}^n{A_2}^n{A_3}^n$ all the way to the right-hand side, **t**ransforming each $A_1$, $A_2$, and $A_3$ to $a$ along the way, as well as updating itself to $T_2$ and then $T_3$ to indicate different phases.

Here is the strategy.

1. $S$ becomes $T_1A$ .
2. $A$ is blown up to ${A_1}^n(A_2A_3)^n$ by rules $A\rightarrow A_1AA_2A_3\mid A_1A_2A_3$.
3. $A_3A_2$ is transformed to $A_2A_3$ repeatedly so that $(A_2A_3)^{n}$ becomes ${A_2}^n{A_3}^n$.
4. $T_1A_1$ is transformed to $aT_1$ repeatedly so that $T_1{A_1}^n$ becomes $a^nT_1$.
5. $T_1A_2$ becomes $bT_2A_2$.
6. $T_2A_2$ is transformed to $aT_2$ repeatedly so that $T_2{A_2}^n$ becomes $a^nT_2$.
7. $T_2A_3$ becomes $bT_3A_3$.
8. $T_3A_3$ is transformed to $aT_3$ repeatedly so that $T_3{A_3}^n$ becomes $a^nT_3$.
9. $T_3$ is changed to b.

Here is the strategy in terms of formal derivation.

$$\begin{aligned} S
&\Rightarrow T_1A\\
&\Rightarrow^* T_1A_1^n(A_2A_3)^n\\
&\Rightarrow^*T_1{A_1}^n{A_2}^n{A_3}^n\\
&\Rightarrow^*a^nT_1{A_2}^n{A_3}^n\\
&\Rightarrow^*a^nbT_2{A_2}^n{A_3}^n\\
&\Rightarrow^*a^nba^nT_2{A_3}^n\\
&\Rightarrow^*a^nba^nbT_3{A_3}^n\\
&\Rightarrow^*a^nba^nba^nT_3\\
&\Rightarrow a^nba^nba^nb
\end{aligned}$$

Here is the context-sensitive grammar, where each of rule (3), rule (4), rule (6), and rule (8) stands for four context sensitive rules as given by the lemmas above. In the case when $0\in\Bbb N$, we should add rule $S\rightarrow bbb$.

\begin{align}
S&\rightarrow T_1A &(1)\\
A&\rightarrow A_1AA_2A_3 \mid A_1A_2A_3 &(2)\\
A_3A_2&\rightarrow A_2A_3 &(3)\\
T_1A_1&\rightarrow aT_1 &(4)\\
T_1A_2&\rightarrow bT_2A_2 &(5)\\
T_2A_2 &\rightarrow aT_2 &(6)\\
T_2A_3 &\rightarrow aT_3A_3 &(7)\\
T_3A_3 &\rightarrow aT_3 &(8)\\
T_3&\rightarrow b &(9)\\
\end{align}

---

**Exercise 1.** Explain why the strings generated by the grammar above must be of the form $a^nba^na^nb$.

**Exercise 2.** Write a grammar for $\{a^nb^{2n}a^{3n} \mid n \in \Bbb N\}$.

**Exercise 3.** Write a grammar for $\{a^{n+n^2} \mid n \in \Bbb N\}$.

Comment: i will try but i think im to stupid

Comment: I do not know you, but I have been too stupid from time to time.

Comment: It should have been "context-sensitive grammar" in exercise 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

I like the feature sensitive grammar notaion, means for each term is a set of features assigned, what must be matched inside a rule.
The rule will be just:

S[a_count = n]-> a{n}b a{n}b a{n}b ,

Compare it to notations above with 10 rules.
While matching the feature rule, parser will mach amount of a's and assign the value to  S.a_count field. Dont forget, a parser is a turing complete program in praxis.

Further, arithmetical expression are possible :

S[a_count = n]-> a{n}b{2*n}c{3*n},

Exercise 3 is not possible with this notation, it is something like :

S[a_count = m]-> a{m} : m == n + n*n , n in N

so equasion must be solved here